# How to know which .whl module is suitable for my system with so many?

Tags: python, python-wheel, python-install

We have so may versions of wheel. 
How could we know which version should be installed into my system?
I remember there is a certain command which could check my system environment.
Or is there any other ways?

---------------------Example Below this line -----------

scikit_learn-0.17.1-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl
scikit_learn-0.17.1-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl
scikit_learn-0.17.1-cp34-cp34m-win32.whl
scikit_learn-0.17.1-cp34-cp34m-win_amd64.whl
scikit_learn-0.17.1-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl
scikit_learn-0.17.1-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
scikit_learn-0.18rc2-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl
scikit_learn-0.18rc2-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl
scikit_learn-0.18rc2-cp34-cp34m-win32.whl
scikit_learn-0.18rc2-cp34-cp34m-win_amd64.whl
scikit_learn-0.18rc2-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl
scikit_learn-0.18rc2-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl

Answer (score 1):

In case this is still an issue, the following should tell you the information you need to know about your architecture to choose a wheel:

```
import platform

print platform.architecture()
```

Comment: For Python 3: `print(platform.architecture)`

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to know.  Use `pip` - it will select the most specific wheel available.

Comment: Sometimes, it doesn't work. There is some circumstance that we have to use those unofficial windows binaries, if we are not using a Windows specific python bundle.

Comment: On Windows, I generally use Christoph Gohlke's wheels, but I just download updates as he builds them and let `pip` decide what to use.

Comment: So you download all of the alternatives?

Comment: More or less.  I currently grab whatever is available for 2.7 because until recently I hadn't been using any 3.x version.  The next time I update my fetching script, I'll start collecting the 3.5 wheels too.

Comment: BTW, do you know how to select between win_amd64 and win32? It's just 64bit system and 32bit system?

Comment: Yes, that's the difference.  Sorry, I thought you knew how the naming works - see this link: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0427/#file-name-convention for details on how to interpret the file names.